# Invoking a Lambda through API-Gateway giving 403 response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, aws-codestar

I am using AWS codestar to deploy by react application using serverless nodejs template. This is the url that is given by codestar after successfully completion of all the stages `https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod` . This url displayed all the components in my app correctly. In navbar of my app i have items like this `a` ,`b`,`c`. where clicking on each one of them will redirect to a new component.(i.e.`https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/a`,`https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/b` etc. But when i refresh the page which is having a url like this `https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/b` i am getting a error like `{"message":"Forbidden"}` and in my console it is showing like this `favicon.ico:1 GET https://xxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/favicon.ico 403`

It seems the chrome is fetching the favicon based on the `https` link, which fails because there is no such `favicon` at the location. I tried to remove `favicon.ico link` in index.html but even then the chrome is using the same url to fetch the favicon which eventually fails. I followed max number of suggestions in SO to acheive this but no luck. Is there any way to say `api-gateway` to exclude these `favicon get requests` and display my app rather than showing `message forbidden`.

And i am pretty sure that i had enabled logs for both the agi-gateway and lambda where i didnt find any forbidden errors(i.e.403) which is weird because i can see those 403 errors in my console.

Thanks
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod` url provided by API Gateway is the base url for your site, so those paths would have to be `/Prod/a` instead of `/a`.

One way to get around that is to register your own domain and connect it to API Gateway via a [custom domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html). That would allow you to have `https://example.com` as your base url, and your paths could stay `/a`, `/b`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. You mean because of this i am getting `{"message":"Forbidden"}` ? Is it not due to `favicon get requests` ?

Comment: Your favicon requests are failing since `https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/favicon.ico` has the wrong url base. I think favicons are requested by browsers automatically at `/favicon.ico`, so you may not be able to change the path to `/Prod/favicon.ico`.

Comment: Yeah what you are saying is exactly right regarding the favicon thing. In your answer you said one way is through custom domain is there any other way  for that since i dont have custom domain because it is not free.

Comment: It looks like browsers request `/favicon.ico` without looking at the page's base url, so even providing a[<base>](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_base.asp) tag wouldn't help. So I don't see another way around the favicon issue. Using a <base> tag could at least simplify your links though, so you wouldn't need `/Prod` in front of all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the `<base>` tag. One question even after using custom domain still it will read the same url right ? Suppose i have custom domain like this `https://www.example.com` then i will assign this with the base url(i.e.`https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod`) . After that i will assign paths to my custom domains like this `https://www.example.com/a`,`https://www.example.com/b` etc. Then when i hit this `https://www.example.com/a` in browser internally it points to `https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/a` only right?

Comment: Because i already tried `https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/a` one without custom domain and it given me `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}`

Comment: Yeah, `https://www.example.com/a` would become the equivalent of hitting `https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/a`. The authN token is a separate issue and is due to your authN type being set to something other than NONE. If you use an authN mechanism, you'll need to provide appropriate credentials (like IAM if your authN is AWS_IAM); otherwise you can just use NONE to not require authN.